# "NSInternalInconsistencyException: threading violation: expected the main thread" outside of my code

Tags: ios

My iOS App is crashing with the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FBSSerialQueue assertOnQueue], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/FrontBoardServices/FrontBoard-626.4.1/FrontBoardServices/FBSSerialQueue.m:98
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'threading violation: expected the main thread'
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Reason: threading violation: expected the main thread

Stacktrace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d56c980 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 1255808
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d285028 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d4694fc DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 193788
3   Foundation                          0x000000018d8aa690 7A7A96AF-79E4-3DB1-8904-42E61CAE8999 + 571024
4   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001927ae7ec 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 366572
5   FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000192760460 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 46176
6   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001927606ec 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 46828
7   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001927605e4 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 46564
8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001911e1c40 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 5995584
9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001912d1870 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 6977648
10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001912d2640 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 6981184
11  CameraUI                            0x00000001afbb8514 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 652564
12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29f3f8 objc_release + 136
13  CameraUI                            0x00000001afc5b118 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 1319192
14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d284130 2C18C54E-6C84-310C-851F-F9602890D908 + 20784
15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d296f80 objc_destructInstance + 92
16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29de44 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
17  CameraUI                            0x00000001afc502c4 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 1274564
18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29f3f8 objc_release + 136
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d4b243c DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 492604
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d43cfc0 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 12224
21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29f3f8 objc_release + 136
22  CameraUI                            0x00000001afcb3704 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 1681156
23  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d284130 2C18C54E-6C84-310C-851F-F9602890D908 + 20784
24  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d296f80 objc_destructInstance + 92
25  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29de44 _objc_rootDealloc + 52
26  CameraUI                            0x00000001afca48ac 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 1620140
27  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29f3f8 objc_release + 136
28  libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x000000018d18fa08 _Block_release + 168
29  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018d29f3f8 objc_release + 136
30  libsystem_blocks.dylib              0x000000018d18fa08 _Block_release + 168
31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d3b27c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d4290c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 720
33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d434fc _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102d4e4dc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 1344
35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018d2776d0 _pthread_wqthread + 280
36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018d27d9e8 start_wqthread + 8
)
```

Is seems to be completely outside of my code. Is there any way to debug this? Is it a bug in an iOS component?

The UIImagePickerController seems to be involved. It seems to happen shortly after picking a foto via the camera.

**EDIT:** Here is what the debug navigator is showing right after the crash:

[image]

And one more screenshot:

[image]

I cannot identify a single action in the app that reproduces the crash. I need to click around in a component that takes a picture from the camera and saves it into a UICollectionView. Only sometimes and eventually, the crash happens at different points.

I've verified that the code inside `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is running on the main thread.

How can I locate the exact place in my the code where this crash is happening?

**EDIT 2**: Update from Apple developer technical support; they believe that it is a bug and they suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: It’s your bug in your code. Symbolicate and show us your code if you want help.

Comment: @matt are you sure about that? My app is not listed in the stacktrace and the output on the top is all I get when I reproduce the crash via Xcode.

Comment: It isn’t _all_ you get. You get all the threads.  If you can reproduce the crash, you know what you were doing and what your code was.  You are still not showing it. Do you want help?

Comment: @matt edited with a screenshot. Does that help? If not, could you please tell me what exactly you need to look at in order to be able to tell more? (For the record: there is not a single, isolated action that reproduces the crash. I need to click around and take several pictures and eventually it happens)

Comment: Look at similar questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880040/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexception. See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Threading+violation+expected+the+main+thread  You’re doing something on a background thread that needs to be done on the main thread. Try to accept that fact and find it. Since you still refuse to show _any_ code you are on your own. I would recommend turning on the thread sanitizer and main thread checker, but sometimes eyeballs and thinking are best.

Comment: @matt yes that is clear and obvious. What is not obvious and what I would like to get some help on is: how can I locate the code that should be running on the main thread but that isn't? (main thread checker is on but doesn't report it and thread sanitizer is not avalable on the device)

Comment: @matt also I would love to show some code but I need to know which part, there are hundrets and hundrets of lines of code in that area.

Comment: guys did you find something more here?

Comment: @BarbaraR As written in "EDIT 2" Apple did confirm that this is a bug in iOS. I have no idea when it will be fixed though.

Comment: thanks. Just a comment I was having the same issue and debugging the orientation changes code was a good way to find out more about this crash. You can check these sources for more information https://github.com/erduoniba/HDCameraCrashDemo Basically pay attention to how you are generating the start and end of the orientation changes notifications. The technique shown in the post will help you to debug and find the issue. But the issue itself could be in the sequence of notifications / the thread you are using for it. Tell me if it helps you.

Comment: @BarbaraR The workaround that did fix it for me was to call the following right after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) { [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; }

Comment: @user1195883 to arrive to a more solid solution without work around you have to make sure you don't do calls to beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications (or end) in a background thread. And also that the calls are balanced beging / end pairs.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS14 UIImagePicker is being deprecated, so I would suggest wrapping your code in an iOS version check and using the new PHPickerViewController instead. Not the best solutions, but it's something.